# parallelism with mysql queries

Tags: mysql, parallel-processing, apache-storm

I have the following problem:

I'm dealing with multiple parallel threads at the moment which simultaneously should get data from the same data base via a mysql query (I'm using Java for this - more precisely, storm with Java). But instead of doing this parallely it seems to be done sequentally and therefore, the time needed for the whole process more or less is the added-up time of each query from every thread.

Is there a way to actually perform these threads (and the queries from the same data base coming along with them) parallely? I really need to speed up the process by a lot.

Unofortunately, there are way too many lines of code to be able to present you some usefull extracts of it...

I hope you can still help me out with this.

Thanks1

Comment: Depends on the queries, some will lock tables, others will not.  Perhaps you need a database cluster instead if I/O or machine power is to blame.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. How can I find out whether my query locks tables or doesn't?

Comment: Generally, it is write operations (INSERT/UPDATE, triggers perhaps) that cause locking.  Read about locking, particularly the internal locking: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/locking-issues.html

Comment: Alright, thanks for the moment. I try to find out more about it using the link.

Comment: Also worth a read: [PHP: How mysqlnd async queries help you with sharding!](http://blog.ulf-wendel.de/?p=201)

Comment: Don't know if it's going to help but setting `query_cache_***(something)` can help

Comment: You need to post an outline of your storm topology and a summary of the bolt which is interacting with MySQL. Otherwise your question can't be understood.